# Swipe pattern matching in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, gesture-recognition

I am trying to make an app that will match a swipe pattern to display a particular image. Currently i am using buttons to display an image on button click. I want to detect a swipe pattern and display images accordingly.
Any help in this direction is welcome. Please help

Comment: on button click, click event will happen and on that u will need to do some animation kind of thing, but if u want "swipe effect" then u have to add swipe gesture on button. So just want to suggest that remove this from ur mind that u will get swipe effect on button click.. u need to swipe button.. not click on button

Answer (score 4):

try this one:

.h file add "`UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`"

.m file (if you want in self.view)

```
   //LEFT Swipe
   UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipedLeft:)];
   [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft ];
   [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

   //Right Swipe
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipedRight:)];
    [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight ];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];

    //Down Swipe        
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeDown = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeDown:)];
    [swipeDown setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown ];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeDown];

    //Up Swipe       
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeUp:)];
    [swipeUp setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp ];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeUp];

- (void)swipedRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{   // Do your stuff while swipedRight
}

- (void)swipedLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{   // Do your stuff while swipedLeft
}
- (void)swipeDown:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{   // Do your stuff while swipeDown
}
- (void)swipeUp:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{   // Do your stuff while swipeUp
}
```

**EDIT:**

**For circular swipe detect**:

check answer given by *Sixten Otto* from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600690/how-to-detect-circular-gesture-via-gesture-recognizer)

also check this thread from [here](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2009/04/detecting-circle-gesture.html)

**For angle swipe** :

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863265/swipe-detection-in-any-angle?rq=1)

May it will help you.

happy coding...:)

Comment: thanks for the help. but i need to check certain swipe patterns.means if user swipes an L,or a square or a circle. Can i do this?? and depending upon the pattern i have to display certain images

Comment: UISwipeGestureRecognizer gives you only four gesture left,right,up,down.may be you have to use third party library for your requirement and mention question proper way what you want exactly.

Comment: i want to detect if a user swiped an L,a square etc. can you please suggest any third party libraries i can look at.

Comment: for that check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313484/recognizing-patterns-when-drawing-over-the-iphone-screen?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                        initWithTarget:self
                                                action:@selector(swipeAction)];
swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipe];


 -(void)swipeAction

{

}
```